# How to assign void* pointer1 to void* pointer2? Facing some problem

Tags: c, memory, pointers

```
void* ptr1 = NULL;
void* ptr2 = ptr1;
unsigned int *buf = data;//some buffer

//now
ptr2 = buf + 8;
```

The above change in address of ptr2 is not reflected in ptr1.
I am trying `void* ptr2 = &ptr1;` too.

Please let me know whats the mistake here.

Comment: @Karthik,Can you please edit the code with some formatting? Also please rephrase the question, it is not easy to understand what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: `void* ptr2 = &ptr1;` - this creates ptr2 as a pointer to type void, the pointer is initialized with the the address of ptr1, which is different than the address of what ptr1 points to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want ptr1 to follow ptr2:

```
void* ptr2 = NULL;
void** ptr1 = (void **)&ptr2;
unsigned int *buf = data;//some buffer

//now
ptr2 = buf + 8;
```

Now *ptr1 follows ptr2

Answer (score 7):

Why would ptr1 follow ptr2?

If you wanted ptr1 to have the same address as ptr2 then you would set it to ptr2:

```
ptr1 = ptr2;
```

In your post ptr1 still points to NULL.  So you need to explicitly tell it to point to ptr2.

Drawing pictures makes it all the more clearer so go at it:

[alt text http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/2433/pointers.png](http://img705.imageshack.us/img705/2433/pointers.png)

Right now you have 2 pointers pointing at some data or no data (NULL).  If you want a pointer to follow another pointer, you want a pointer to a pointer (2 asterisks) not just a pointer (1 asterisk).

```
void** ptr1  = (void**) &ptr2;
```

Comment: Note that pt2 actually points to buf+8 and so I am no artist, picture doesnt show the actual memory :).

Answer (score 4):

A pointer *points* to an object. Changing a pointer means making it point elsewhere. It does not alter the pointed-to object, nor does it impact any other pointer to that object.

Here, you have `ptr1` and `ptr2` which are independent variables, each containing a pointer value. If you want changes to one being reflected on the other, then you actually do not want two independent variables, you want just one, and use it several times.

Answer (score 4):

This is what happens :

[image: This is what happens]

Comment: @JonH, I had not seen your "idea" when I took the time to draw this. (which is quite obvious by the way, quite pretentious of you to imagine I had to copy your idea to come up with that.) Since you seem upset about this, I've upvoted your reply.

Comment: @David V. - Does look better then mine +1.

Comment: @JonH, if you intended to +1 my response, you actually forgot to :)

Comment: @David V., What did you use to draw this? Neat!

Comment: @Agnel Kurian, I used inkscape ( www.inkscape.org )

Answer (score 2):

You have to manually update `ptr1` - it's a variable completely unrelated to `ptr2` and they change values independently.